# how to create the effect that the image stands out from the background?

Tags: css, user-interface, tailwind-css, css-position

I would like to create somethign like this https://dribbble.com/shots/17227956-Music-Landing-Page-Concept-UX-UI-Design to make it look like the image is standing out from its background. I can do that, but I'm having trouble with the image not being centered. But I do not know how to set image to the center and bottom to be overflow

How it looks on my page[image]

Code:

```
<div class="text-center flex flex-col relative">
   <div class="hidden md:flex mx-auto flex flex-row   items-center">
     <p class="mr-4 text-white font-extrabold leading-tight text-4xl flex">Let the 
      music</p>
     <div class="bg-other h-48 w-48 rounded-full overflow-hidden  shadow-lg z-10">
       <img src="Sources/img/assets/people_music_login.png" alt="people" class="object- 
       cover h-full absolute top-0  left-12  " />
     </div>
    <p class="ml-4 text-white font-extrabold leading-tight text-4xl flex">carry you away</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: check this: https://css-tricks.com/a-fancy-hover-effect-for-your-avatar/

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the image, I mean the simplest method would be starting with an image who is made in such a way it looks like coming outside of background. Otherwise you can code them the way you wanted with threejs or babylonjs. But that way the images will be 3d models which seems more appealing for UX. The choice is yours